# (Excel) Neither Offset nor Index/Match prevented a table's referenced cell from moving

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula, formatting, reporting

I have a report that consists of 3 different input, and 3 corresponding output tabs for 3 different sources of information. Each source needed a Macro to change the formatting of the data. One of these sources needs data for individual days, so as it formats the data into a table, it is copying and inserting the cells on top of the previous day's data. Once 5 days of data has been converted and stacked in the output tab, a final tab has essentially all the formula's, dubbed the "Conversion" tab. In this tab there are 3 tables for each source of data (the output tabs) and a fourth that takes the data from these 3 tables, and combines them into what a final macro copies and pastes the values from into a new sheet.

The problem lies in that sheet that stacks the data by inserting the new rows. I've done everything from Index and match, Offset and match, simple offset, Vlookup (obviously, that's the go-to at first) and even Defined the name of new formula's, but the cell that the Conversion tab's table references keeps moving down as new data comes in. I need to reference Array 'CampPerf Output'!B116:B135
no matter what. What formula can I use or backdoor trick can I use so that my lookup looks at the exact same array every time?

The macro that converts the data has to be a repeatable action so I can assign it to a button (This report must be made as simple as possible, as Non-Excel Users need to be capable of "paste data, click button, click other button, ta-da!")

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Always `B116:B135 ` same column and rows no matter what, without changing when rows and columns are added or subtracted?

Comment: Thats correct. Well its correct for the "Monday data". Tuesdays data is Array  'CampPerf Output'!B89:B111, Wednesday is 'CampPerf Output'! B62:B84, and so on....

Comment: Them my answer will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as your range reference:

```
INDEX('CampPerf Output'!$1:$1048576,116,2):INDEX('CampPerf Output'!$1:$1048576,135,2)
```

This will always return the range array in `'CampPerf Output'!B116:B135` no matter how many rows or columns are added or removed.

Comment: This worked incredibly! From now I'll use the limits of the sheet coordinates as my braces to keep the data from moving around. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.